# Clearing share image cache using OG Object Debugger no longer seems to work?

Tags: facebook, caching, facebook-like

I have a share link image that I need to change.
I remember some time ago finding some posts describing that the [Object Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) would clear the image cache for that URL (there are also a number of those here on SO). It worked fine back then, but now it seems to have stopped working.

The thumbnail shown is still the old one.
If I copy/paste the og:image URL that the debugger shows into a browser, the new image shown correctly, so Facebook obviously still caches it.

Has anyone had similar experiences, and is there any alternative methods to clear the cache?

Comment: ... my apologies for the horrible tagging with "caching", but SO forced me to choose a non-FB related tag.